# How can I stop Chromium from putting focus in the address bar when using the up arrow key to scroll to the top of a page?

Tags: ubuntu, scrolling, chromium

This is bugging me. I'm at a web page, any web page, and I am scrolling back to the top of the page with the up arrow key as I tend to do when browsing a page and once I get to the top of the page if I don't pay attention and hit the key one more times than is needed Chromium in all it's wisdom decides I must want to do something with the address so it places the focus in the address bar. ARGH!

Any way to stop this?

I'm running Ubuntu 9.04 Jaunty and have installed the nightly build version of Chromium PPA.

Comment: Funny, I can't replicate this in Google Chrome on WinXP

Comment: wasn't sure, that's why I didn't tag it Chrome, I'll update the question to state I'm on the linux nightly release version of chromium on ubuntu.

Comment: Nether can I; also Google Chrome, but in XP, Vista and 7.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the dev build out into beta?
I am running chrome 4.202
Do check out if the same problem is persisting in chrome 4 beta too?

Answer (score 0):

This may not answer your question, but in pretty much any browser I've used supports hitting the 'Home' key to return to the top of the page. This includes Chrome.

Have you considered this option?

Comment: yes that is something I use as well, but it's not too handy for 'scrolling' up through a page, which is my use case here.